If I was ever deported, would it only be to my country of citizenship? Or can I arrange something else?
Say you are in a foreign country, and get deported, for whatever reason. How many countries, in this process of deporting, will enforce deportation to the country of citizenship, and how many countries do not really care and will let you go to any other country instead?
I live in Ukraine, but I was born in Russia, and I was not able to obtain citizenship of Ukraine. I also have donated large sums of money to the Ukrainian Army, have actually raised money for the Army on multiple occasions since 2022, and have been volunteering. This means that in Russia that would be, I guess, at least 20 years in prison, until that regime is defeated.
So, if it is very important for me that even in the event of deportation, the foreign country does not enforce deportation to Russia, what countries should I avoid at all costs and what are safe?
Also, in case I decide to move to another country, do you think it makes sense to try to obtain refugee status there, for extra safety?

IANAL, but I suspect that what will happen will depend on the country, the situation, and the people involved. It sounds like you should try to get refugee status; you are likely to be prosecuted for political reasons if you would return to Russia.

See here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/27628/how-to-ensure-you-are-not-deported-back-to-your-country-of-origin-without-being

At the very least, they can only send you to a country that's willing to accept you. And if you've done something punishable by deportation, there may not be very many of those, other than your country of citizenship. Even countries that you could normally enter visa-free might refuse you at that point

Germany deports a stateless man who lived in Germany his entire life to a country he's never been, so your citizenship certainly doesn't matter.  You are not safe until you are a naturalised citizen.

In the event that you emigrate to another country and later end up in a position where you no longer will be able to have a legal status (lost job, no longer studying, etc) and as such will generally be asked to leave (initially) voluntarily, you may still have the option to apply for asylum. Do keep a good set of documents around showing your activities that would get you persecuted in Russia as proof.

This will depend a lot on which country would be deporting you and what you did to get deported.

Are you asking about moving to another country through some non-refugee immigration scheme (e.g., a work visa) and then you're convicted of a crime?  Let it not be a serious crime, because that can result in forfeiture of refugee protections. But in general you shouldn't be sent to your country of citizenship if you reasonably fear persecution there for the reasons covered by the convention. Better still: don't do anything that will get you deported. If they can't deport you to Russia and can't find another country to accept you, you could be in immigration detention for the rest of your life.

I am not sure this is a suitable question for Travel SE. Travellers could give you answers, but this is a very special circumstance considering that Ukraine and Russia are at war. Can you contact a lawyer in Ukraine?

Avoid Belarus at all cost.

@AgnishomChattopadhyay Might fit better at [Expats.SE].

"until that regime is defeated" - even in the event of a change of government, I wouldn't assume this goes away. By your own testimony, you're directly sponsoring an army fighting against the country of your citizenship, which is something most countries frown on. In your place I'd be doing anything possible to change my citizenship.

I would like them to deport me to Bermuda every year, around August.

If you are able to find a country that permits you to enter, you can simply travel there and are not any longer in danger of being deported now, are you? Unless you are trying to make the former host country pay for your fare.

Your question has no simple answer. In the UK you can be deported to the country of which you are a national, but also to any other country where you may be acceptable.  So if you have permanent residence in another country you could be sent there. But other countries may have quite different laws on this.
There are arrangements for transit flights where it's not possible to send someone directly to their deportee destination. Often involving being escorted by a security person (to prevent you disappearing at the intermediate airport.)


Say you are in a foreign country, and get deported, for whatever reason. How many countries, in this process of deporting, will enforce deportation to the country of citizenship, and how many countries do not really care and will let you go to any other country instead?

“Deportation” is typically used for a removal based on a judicial decision, e.g. after committing a crime. It's difficult to generalize to all countries in the world but I wouldn't expect the authorities to “let you go” anywhere. In other situations, you may be given some opportunity to leave on your own (“voluntary departure”), sometimes with a financial incentive but if we are talking about deportation, you are probably in detention and being coerced to leave.
So if you are facing some form of “enforced removal” (including deportation), you are already in a more dire situation. In that case, what typically happens is that the police will escort you onto the plane, possibly all the way to the destination where they hand you over to the local police. Removals need to be cleared in advance with the consulate of the destination country, which will issue a laissez-passer to replace your passport (if you don't have one, which is a common scenario for a removal).
If you are a Russian citizen, the local authorities are highly likely to ask the Russian consulate first and will not, in any case, deport you to a country where they are not certain you will be admitted. The only (partial) exception would be a removal at the port of entry, happening immediately after you presented yourself to the border, where you could simply be sent back to the point of origin of your flight (but that's not a deportation and you wrote in your question that you were already in the country).

So, if it is very important for me that even in the event of deportation, the foreign country does not enforce deportation to Russia, what countries should I avoid at all costs and what are safe?
Also, in case I decide to move to another country, do you think it makes sense to try to obtain refugee status there, for extra safety?

That's exactly what international protection is for. If you are a refugee, you should not face removal to your country of citizenship and should be able to continue to live in the country even without a passport.
The bit about the passport is important: If you don't have a valid passport, there is no reason to think you will be accepted anywhere and the only option for removal is a country that will recognize you as a citizen and issue a laissez-passer. Conversely, if you renewed your passport after leaving then the assumption is that you do not fear the Russian authorities, that you are not really a refugee, and can safely be removed there.

Some countries* differentiate between expulsion, where you are told to leave the country in the next X days, and deportation, where you are physically made to leave the country.**
I would imagine it is hard to choose your destination in case of an actual deportation. But in case of an expulsion, countries usually do not care where you go as long as you do indeed leave.


or maybe "most countries" or even "all countries", but I only know it for sure in the case of Germany

** The respective German terms are Ausweisung and Abschiebung.

I don't think this terminology is common at all in English sources. Do you mean to translate some German terms?

@Relaxed "expulsion" is a familiar term in the context of diplomats (who generally fit the description above). I don't really recall hearing it in other contexts, but is that because it's not used, or because it's less notable and so not publicized? Plus the factor that people tend to use "deportation" too broadly, there's plenty of evidence of that on this site.

@user111403 Yes and in fact this answer is an example of that: Deportation typically has an even narrower meaning and does not necessarily cover all cases where someone is physically escorted out of a country. I suspect a better translation would be (en)forced removal but I am still not sure what the OP meant.

@Relaxed after a bit of Googling, it seems the term is used officially by the EU. https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/networks/european-migration-network-emn/emn-asylum-and-migration-glossary/glossary/expulsion_en

@user111403 I didn't know that. The definition seems different and somewhat confusing, tough. “Removal” implies being physically made to leave the country (what the answer calls “deportation”) while “Ausweisung” or “éloignement” are indeed decisions issued prior to any enforcement action (so what the answer call “expulsion”). That terminology is entirely absent from the more recent Returns directive where you will find the more familiar “return decision” and “removal”.

@Relaxed removal is a relatively new term; any distinction between removal and deportation depends entirely on the definitions given to those terms in a particular legal system.  I don't believe they mean the same things in the US and the UK, for example.  Anyone who wants to use these terms generally across systems, or with respect to a system with laws written in languages other than English, should define them explicitly as well for their own purposes.  For a question such as this, the important thing is the different possible mechanisms rather than the words denoting them.

@phoog Yes, indeed, that's also why I strive to use the proper terminology in the local language when discussing specific cases but to come back to the start of the discussion, that's exactly why I found this answer confusing. It's clearly based on German practice (and to the author's credit, he did state that explicitly) but uses a terminology that does not seem to be in use in any country or organization using English as a working language. In my opinion, the answer is much better now that it mentions he actual German terms and it could possibly suggest several translations.

If you meet criteria for claiming asylum in country A and if country A has a safe third country agreement with country B and if you have some tie to country B (perhaps you traveled through B to reach A), then A may remove you to B instead of to your actual country of citizenship. The downside to this for you is that these agreements are in place so that country A can remove people faster, so in that kind of circumstance you are more likely to be removed from country A.
You really need to talk to an immigration lawyer about how you can achieve legal residence in some country that is not Russia and then this problem of where you might be removed to goes away.

Resident status is definitely not an international protection against deportation.

@MadHatter usually deportation would have to be preceded by the formal cancellation of the resident status.  Regardless, someone with resident status who faces deportation can at that point make a case against the deportation on the basis of the refugee convention.  It's not necessary for the conditions leading to refugee status to have existed at the time of entry to the country of refuge.

@phoog true, though most of that applies even if the applicant isn't resident at the time of proceedings commencing.  In any case, I'm not saying that LPR (or equivalent) status doesn't make it harder for someone to be deported to their country of citizenship, but I am challenging the author's assertion that acquisition of such status means that "this problem of where you might be removed to goes away".

@MadHatter Let me say rather "becomes a much more acceptable level of risk", more on par with normal everyday risks like the possibility of being hit by a car or something.

Do feel free to say that!
